# Getting wrong numbers from prefix array

Tags: c++, loops, output, prefix

in my program I've been trying to get an input from user, and check if the letters in it were small or capital, and then make a prefix array, where I would check if the number of next small and big letters (counting from the begging of the word) was the same. I wanted to do that by assignig big letters value 1 and -1 to small ones.

My problem is that after I load the word from user to my array, and then want to make prefix array, the numbers don't match - in my opinion.

My input is:

> STaSzIc

And my output is:

```
 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 

1 1
2 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
```

Why after 3'rd value, next don't work?
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Caps;
    int tab[1000000];
    cin >> Caps;
    for(int i = 1; i <= Caps.length(); i++){
        if(Caps[i - 1] <= 90){
            tab[i] = 1;
            cout<<tab[i]<<' ';
        }else{
            tab[i] = -1;
            cout<<tab[i]<<' ';
            
        }
        
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    int prefiksy[1000000];
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= Caps.length(); i++){
        prefiksy[i] = tab[i] + tab[i - 1];
        cout<<prefiksy[i]<<" "<<i<<endl;
    }
    
}
```

I was hoping for such result:

```
1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 
    
    1 1
    2 2
    1 3
    2 4
    1 5
    2 6
    1 7
```

Comment: `+ tab[i - 1];` you don't initialize `tab[0]` before use.

Comment: Isn't it 0 by deafult?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: `tab[i] + tab[i - 1]` only calculates the difference between the current and previous element, you don't keep a total tally if that's what you mean

Comment: Also currently your `prefiksy` array is useless since you never read from it, maybe that's the error

Comment: `int tab[1000000];` could be an additional problem. On msvc it would likely cause a stack overflow.

Comment: So how should I do it?

Comment: Start with using a `std::vector<int>` instead of `int tab[1000000];` and `int prefiksy[1000000];`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Caps;
    int tab[100]={0};
    cin >> Caps;
    for(int i = 1; i <= Caps.length(); i++){
        if(Caps[i - 1] <= 90){
            tab[i] = 1;
            cout<<tab[i]<<' ';
        }else{
            tab[i] = -1;
            cout<<tab[i]<<' ';

        }

    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    int prefiksy[100];
    prefiksy[1] = tab[1];
    cout<<prefiksy[1]<<" "<<1<<endl;
    for(int i = 2; i <= Caps.length(); i++){
        prefiksy[i]=prefiksy[i-1]+tab[i];
        cout<<prefiksy[i]<<" "<<i<<endl;
    }

}
```

Check this statement `prefiksy[i] = tab[i] + tab[i - 1];`.The logic of the code is wrong. Do trace table for `prefiksy[i]`. You are trying to add only value of array `tab` to `prefiksy` which is not the intention of the algorithm. You need to mind the value of array 'prefiksy' at each iteration as well because it is going to be the value for the upcoming series in the question. Also it is always better to initialize an array after it's creation. Practice more, you'll understand and get better.